# Servicestack monotouch DLL built using PCL

Tags: xamarin.ios, servicestack, xamarin, mvvmcross, portable-class-library

I'm migrating a solution to MVVMCross but the ServiceStack client libraries are difficult to work with.

How can I build ServiceStack client DLL into PCL library for use in Xamarin Studio so it's multi platform?

There is nothing of note here unless I missed it:  https://github.com/ServiceStack

Answer (score 3):

You could clone the ServiceStack project, make a PCL project, link the files, build, and see what is missing.  I'm sure there is a reason there isn't a PCL already but if you happen to get it going, make a pull request.

Since you're using MvvmCross another option is to make a plugin for your API then reference the ServiceStack libs in the platform specific projects.

You could also use the MvvmCross RestClient and make the same calls the ServiceStack client would make.

edit: A 4th alternative is to use the new HttpClient's.  The one from Xamarin and the other from MS (if you're targeting Win).  Add in [PortableRest](https://github.com/advancedrei/PortableRest) and you'd be able to keep most of the code in a portable.  I say most because you might have to abstract out the HttpClient.  I've used this approach a few times and it works pretty well.  There is a [fork](https://github.com/denisroschinenko/PortableRest/tree/master/src) of PortableRest that added file uploads.

Comment: Great suggestions Derek. First one seems a bit tedious but guess I I may have to at some point but I'm coding in Xamarin Studio and dont have a personal full VS license, for this project so maybe be timeconsuming and unnecessarilly involved <cringe>. Second one is achievable but I still feel a bit dirty with duplicated logic. According to posts, the third option also needs custom platform specific implementations. But if someone does implement a PCL library of Servicestack that would be the best!! <fingers crossed>

Comment: I think I remember Demis saying he wasn't going to implement PCL's for SS but that was a while back.  Added 4th option.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into some issues related to .net (e.g. Timer class is missing in .net 4.5). So I just created a different library and then created a wrapper for the timer class. This is one way of doing it. Having your http code in a separate library would make the project easier to maintain.

One step further would be to use mvvmcross dependency injection to instantiate the class you have created in the other library. That way, even if you are instantiating non-PCL code it does not matter, the thing just works. You will have to declare all your interfaces in a separate PCL library though.